# SSH remote user need to be logged in?

Tags: ssh, encryption, sshd, ecryptfs

I'm trying to set up an SSH server.  I put my public key in the authorized_keys file, made sure the permissions were correct, etc.

When I restart the server (really just Ubuntu 12.04 desktop) and I ssh to it *without* first logging in on the server, I am asked for a password.  If, however, I log into the server, I can ssh without being asked for a password.

`auth.log` has these lines when I have not logged in on the actual server:

```
mordor sshd[1605]: debug1: trying public key file /home/buck/.ssh/authorized_keys
mordor sshd[1605]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/buck/.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could it be that `/home` or `/home/buck` is not mounted before the first user log in? Could you paste the output of `df`?

Comment: Are you using encrypted home directories?

Comment: this belongs on ubuntu.

Comment: @sarnold yes, that was the issue

Comment: @DanielA.White I'll keep that in mind for next time.  I wasn't familiar with the different SE sites.

Comment: @buck: that's part of the problem with the different SE sites -- this could go here (well, I won't bother voting to close..) or [su] or [sf] or [ubuntu.se] or [linux.se]...

Comment: Because this turned out to be an issue with encrypted-home, that's what made it an Ubuntu question.  But the submitter shouldn't sweat it that he didn't know it was Ubuntu-specific, since he wasn't to know what was the cause.  And it's easy enough for a moderator to move it later :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem usually arises if your home directory is encrypted. The usual solution is to put your keys in a directory other than your home directory, and point your `sshd_config` file to it.

For example:

1. Move your authorized_keys file on the server from `/home/buck/.ssh/authorized_keys` to something like `/etc/ssh/keys/buck/authorized_keys`
2. set the permissions on this folder and the keys file: `sudo chown -R buck:buck /etc/ssh/keys/buck/` and `chmod 700 /etc/ssh/keys/buck/` and `chmod 600 /etc/ssh/keys/buck/authorized_keys`
3. Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and change the line `AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `AuthorizedKeysFile      /etc/ssh/keys/%u/authorized_keys`
4. `sudo service ssh restart` and you should be able to login without having to login to the server first.

Comment: awesome, thank you!  The only error I ran into was that it should be %u instead of %h in the sshd_config line (to substitute username instead of home directory).